# Re gex who finds the integer in parenthesis and outside integer before parenthesis

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group, regex-greedy

I need a Regex that finds the integer in parenthesis and outside integer before parenthesis. For example, say I have a string :

```
[ART.117.4002] Adapter Runtime (Adapter Service): Unable to invoke adapter service ost.app.ezycom.adapter:Statement_insertBatch.
[ADA.1.316] Cannot execute the SQL statement "INSERT INTO  dbo.Statement(AccountId, InvoiceId, DocumentType, SoldTo, ShipTo, Division, Works, Date, DateDue, DateDiscountDue, DiscountedAmount, Currency, Amount, ClaimRef, FolderPath, FileName, InvoiceMass, Amount_GST) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)". "
**-3(0) 1(1) -3(2) -3(3) -3(4) 2(5) 1(6) **
(22001/8152) String or binary data would be truncated."
String or binary data would be truncated.
```

I need  regex to find out 
-3(0) 1(1) -3(2) -3(3) -3(4) 2(5) 1(6) from the entire string. Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/lFPg6T/1/):

```
\d+\(\d+\)
```

Or [this](https://regex101.com/r/Tju1S1/3) to match contiguously:

```
(-?\d+\(\d+\)\s?)+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
-\d+\(\d+\)(?:\s-?\d+\(\d+\))*
```

### Demo

By the way, I wonder what values you are binding to your `INSERT` statement to get these errors, but perhaps this is the scope of another question.

Comment: How about `(-?\d+\s*\(\d+\))*` ?

Comment: @kaza Not the same thing.  That would match, for example, `-1(1)(2)-(3)`, which may not be valid input.

Comment: The optional question mark is only on the `-` sign. I put  a `\s` as there was a space after the first pair.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I have tried the regex provided by you but it is not giving me the desired output , It could be because i have edited the error string in the question , Could you please help.The only change i have done is "there is a space between each batch insert record i.e. -3(0) 1(1) -3(2) -3(3) -3(4) 2(5) 1(6)  " in the string

Comment: @GirirajBanshiwala You changed your input data without telling us.  Try my updated answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Many Thanks Tim , it helps.

Comment: @GirirajBanshiwala The answer given by sweaver2112 should also work, though it does not exactly match your data.  But it probably doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi Tim , when i pass the regex suggested by you as a  string it doesn't give the desired results. Please suggest in case if we pass this regex as string do we need to escape it ? Also what will be the regex with escape sequence , Could you please suggest.

Comment: What tool/language are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi Tim ,

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution is to match the (optional) dash, a sequence of at least one digit, followed by a left paren, another sequence of at least one digit, and a right paren.  All matches are demonstrated in [the following demo](https://regex101.com/r/uaZP64/4/) of:

```
-?\d+\(\d+\)(\s+-?\d+\(\d+\))*
```

(it includes the nonmatching sequence you posted in a comment to another answer)  If you know that always the sequence will be preceded by two `**` sequences, then it can be improved (but you don't say that in your request)  The regexp assumes you need a space to separate each subsequence, if the subsequences can stuck together, then substitute `\s+` by `\s*` in the above regex.